# fast conversion of IplImage to Numpy array

Tags: opencv, numpy

The newer OpenCV documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html) says you can convert an IplImage to a Numpy array just like this:

```
arr = numpy.asarray( im )
```

but that doesn't work for my needs, because it apparently doesn't support math:

```
x = arr/0.01
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'cv2.cv.iplimage' and 'float'
```

If I try to specify data type, I can't even get that far:

```
arr = numpy.asarray( im, dtype=num.float32 )
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

So I'm using the code provided in the older documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface). Basically, it does this:

```
arr = numpy.fromstring( im.tostring(), dtype=numpy.float32 )
```

But the `tostring` call is really slow, perhaps because it's copying the data? I need this conversion to be really fast and not copy any buffers it doesn't need to. I don't think the data are inherently incompatible; I'm creating my IplImage with `cv.fromarray` in the first place, which is extremely fast and accepted by the OpenCV functions.

Is there a way I can make the newer `asarray` method work for me, or else can I get direct access to the data pointer in the IplImage in a way that `numpy.fromstring` will accept it? I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1 prepackaged for Ubuntu Precise.

Comment: OpenCV is under heavy development, also the Python bindings. You should try OpenCV 2.4.2 or 2.4.3rc first.

Comment: The question is valid. There is already some legacy Python code for OpenCV `cv` bindgins. They are still supported as of OpenCV 2.4.2. Converting them to `cv2` may not always be an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fun Fact: 
Say you call:

```
import cv2.cv as cv    #Just a formality!

Capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
Img = cv.QueryFrame(Capture)
```

The object `Img` is an `ipimage`, and `numpy.asarray(Img)` is erratic **at best**. However! `Img[:,:]` is a `cvmat` type, and `numpy.asarray(Img[:,:])` works fantastically, and more important: quickly!

This is by far the fastest way I've found to grab a frame and make it an `ndarray` for numpy processing.

Comment: Awesome, I will try that. It won't be soon, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

That page does not say about `IplImage`. It says about `CvMat` which is different.

Anyway you'd better use wrappers from newer `cv2` namespace. It natively uses numpy arrays instead of own image containers. Also the whole `cv` module is considered deprecated and will be completely dropped in the nearest major release.

Comment: You mean I should use `cv2.fromarray()` or something like that, and then `numpy.asarray()` will magically work? Can you provide a link to docs?

Comment: Also, how the *#@$ was anybody supposed to know this? I've been using OpenCV off and on since version 0.1, and I always run away screaming. It's like a horror movie -- I'm afraid there will be a monster behind the door, but I open it anyway.