# Get Numpy array from the frame token by cv.QueryFrame

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming

I want to save a video with `cv2.VideoWriter()` from

```
self.capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
```

but it seems that video.Writer() takes a numpy array.is there anyway to do this without saving the picture and then read it again?
here is the code

```
cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', -1,fps, framesize, is_Color)
frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
video.Write(frame)
video.Release()
```

this gets an error :

> TypeError: frame is not a numpy array,neither a scalar

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104161/fast-conversion-of-iplimage-to-numpy-array

Comment: @RahulKP perfect thank you

Comment: it was as_array = numpy.asarray( cv.GetMat( frame ) )